# Automatically close an output window from a python script

Tags: python, window

I have written a little script to batch plot some data. This script cannot run without a window displaying the newly created plot opening. It stops running till the window is manually closed, then the script continues to run. So my question is as follows:

Is there a way automatically close an output window from within a python script?

Here is the script

```
import pynbody
import numpy as np
import pynbody.plot.sph as sph

f = open('files.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
     line = line[0:-1]
     s = pynbody.load(line)
     sph.image(s.gas,qty="temp",width=16, filename=line[0:-6]+line[-5:len(line)],  units='K',  cmap="YlOrRd",  ret_im=False , approximate_fast=False)

#At the end of the loop I would like to close the output window so the script 
#will continue to run
```

The pynbody.plot.sph package seems as it should be able to turn the output window on and off within the sph.image function call but I have exhausted all the possibilities and am now resorting to this to get the script running.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: linux (Mageia KDE 4.11)

Comment: Ok, well I can't help you on the specifics, but on windows, the window should show up as a separate process.  If you can find the PID you can kill it with ```os.kill()```

Comment: I need to kill about 100 windows :P

Comment: Right, but if your script can find the PIDs, its no extra work for you

Comment: so I should be able to do that from inside the python script?

Comment: If your windows spawn as individual processes I know you can do it in Windows, so it should be doable on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395659/view-and-then-close-the-figure-automatically-in-matplotlib)

[view and then close the figure automatically in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395659/view-and-then-close-the-figure-automatically-in-matplotlib)

Essentially, here's the answer:

```
plt.show(block=False) # block = False allows automatic closing of the image
# the following command will close the graph in 3 seconds
time.sleep(3)
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the  [documentation](http://pynbody.github.io/pynbody/plot.html#pynbody.plot.sph.image), you should set the     noplot argument to True

Comment: The little blurb at the end of the post was to clarify that I have exhausted all the options that the function gives me. I have read the documentation and tried setting noplot=True as well as the ret_im flag.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line **pynbody.plot.plt.close()** to the for loop.

> Definition:  pynbody.plot.plt.close(*args) Docstring: Close a figure
>   window.
>
> `close()` by itself closes the current figure
>
> `close(h)` where *h* is a :class:`Figure` instance, closes that
>   figure
>
> `close(num)` closes figure number *num*
>
> `close(name)` where *name* is a string, closes figure with that
>   label
>
> `close('all')` closes all the figure windows