# How do I close a Window that is opened with plot()? - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, igraph

Using python, I want to plot one graph, wait for 1 second, and plot another graph. The code that I have so far is:

```
from igraph import *
import time

vertices = ["one", "two", "three"]

edges = [(0,2),(2,1),(0,1)]
g = Graph(vertex_attrs={"label": vertices}, edges=edges, directed=True)
plot(g)

time.sleep(1)

edges = [(2,0),(1,2),(1,0)]
g = Graph(vertex_attrs={"label": vertices}, edges=edges, directed=True)
plot(g)
```

The problem is that I have to close the emerging window manually. So, how do I close the window with a python instuction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is possible with matplotlib - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40395659/7019148