# How to close matplotlib animation window after a given time?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, random

This is an animation I made with matplotlib, where dots are randomly moving in a circle.
I want the animation to stop (and the window to close) after 4 seconds.
I tried to set a timer and put the plotting in a while loop, but it doesn't do the work, it keeps running.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from scipy.spatial import distance
import random
import datetime, time

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
then = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
circle_r=2
def get_initial_coordinates():
    x_coord =[random.uniform(3, 7) for i in range(n_particles)]
    y_coord = [random.uniform(3, 7) for i in range(n_particles)]
    return x_coord, y_coord

def get_initial_velocities():
    x_vel = [3 * (np.random.random() - 0.5) * box_width for i in range(n_particles)]
    y_vel = [3 * (np.random.random() - 0.5) * box_width for i in range(n_particles)]
    return x_vel, y_vel

def take_step(x_coord, y_coord, x_vel, y_vel):
    for i in range(n_particles):
     x_coord[i] += x_vel[i]*dt
     y_coord[i] += y_vel[i]*dt
     if distance.euclidean([5, 5], [x_coord[i],y_coord[i]]) >= 3:
         x_vel[i] = -x_vel[i]
         x_coord[i] += x_vel[i] * dt
         y_vel[i] = -y_vel[i]
         y_coord[i] += y_vel[i] * dt

    return x_coord, y_coord, x_vel, y_vel

n_particles = 40
box_width = 10
n_steps = 5000
dt = 0.001

x_coord, y_coord = get_initial_coordinates()
x_vel, y_vel = get_initial_velocities()
for i in range(n_steps):
    x_coord,y_coord,x_vel,y_vel= take_step(x_coord,y_coord,x_vel,y_vel)
#---------------------
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
d, = ax.plot([x_coord[i] for i in range(n_particles)],
             [y_coord[i] for i in range(n_particles)], 'ro')
x_coord, y_coord = get_initial_coordinates()
x_vel, y_vel = get_initial_velocities()
circle = plt.Circle((5, 5), 3, color='blue', fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circle)
def animate(i):
    take_step(x_coord, y_coord, x_vel, y_vel)
    d.set_data([x_coord[i]for i in range(n_particles)],
               [y_coord[i]for i in range(n_particles)])
    return d,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20)
while then > datetime.datetime.now():
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it with `block = False` parameter and a `plt.pause()` as here:

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20, repeat=False)
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(1)
```

[image]

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395799/9214357) and the `plt.show()` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you! This is working. Do you have any suggestion for closing the window when the animation stops? I tried the plt.close(), but it didnt work

Comment: Nothing more than the above instructions. I use PyCharm as IDE and there, using the code above, the animation closes after around 4 seconds.